# PHP Session Variable inside SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

I have this SQL query with a SESSION inside a PHP like below:

```
    $SceneQuery = "SELECT * FROM scene_table_".$_SESSION['ParentState']."";
```

I have this SESSION variable inside the "FROM" clause of the SQl query. It works perfectly fine in my local host but when I uploaded it to my online host which is provided by SiteGround, the query seems not work. Can you guys take a look and suggest me what I should do with this?

Comment: Is it giving an error, or just doing nothing? If it is throwing an error (or warning), what is it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "seems not work"? What error are you getting?

Comment: Explain : Why you want to use `sessions` , why don't make a variable or if you really need session then from where is it coming ? , the possible cause of this is simple that your session index does not contain anything and the identification of the table is null.

Comment: It doesn't give me any error. It just doesn't pull out any data from the the tables which I uploaded to my host. For instance, I have 3 tables which are: scene_table_normal, scene_table_angry and scene_table_happy . If the $_SESSION['ParentState'] = normal, it will pull out the data from scene_table_normal. It works on my local host but it doesn't work when I upload it to my online website. I tried to physically modify the that query to "scene_table_normal" in the file and it worked online, but it didn't work the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. It's because of the case sensitive. When I do a SELECT query from my local host, it ignores the upper case, but when I do it on my online host, it takes the case sensitive into the account. Thanks guys !